# JSON Data $.Each function on top ten results

Tags: jquery, json, each

I currently have a json data feed that I would like to use only the "top ten" results from.

Here is my current code:

```
$.each(data.Categories, function (keyCat, valueCat) 
{
   //perform some actions here
});
```

I would like to only do this for the data.Categories of the highest 10 `valueCat.Value` if the `data.Categories.length > 10`. The `valueCat.Value` is simply a number of items in that category.

I hope this is clear enough...

Comment: Is there a reason that using the built in array sort method and then a for loop wouldn't work?

Comment: Is `data.Categories` already sorted by length?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** If possible, sort data.Categories server-side, this will be faster/more reliable, then the below answers will work.

Assuming data.Categories are sorted, this would work:

```
$.each(data.Categories, function (index, valueCat) {
    if(index<10) {
        //perform some actions here
    } else {
        return false; //break out of $.each()
    }
});
```

Or if Categories is an object:

```
var i=0
$.each(data.Categories, function (keyCat, valueCat) {
    i++;
    if(i<10) {
        //perform some actions here
    } else {
        return false; //break out of $.each()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need to use jQuery for any of this. It can easily be handled by vanilla JavaScript features:

```
data.Categories.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.Value - b.Value;
});

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var valueCat = data.Categories[i];
    // Perform Some Actions Here
}
```